# Calculating and generates a report card for a student

Tags: c++, beginner, console, io

I'm working on this small program for practice and would like to know how I could improve it from here. I'm still a relative beginner with C++ and would like to know if there is a better why to design this program.

Things I want to do:

- Implement a while loop so that the program will continue to take input and write to the file  until the user is done.
- Use and `ifstream` as a way to input the data instead of through the console and write the results to the output file.

Thoughts? Other things I can implement to build on my current knowledge?

```
// Calculates and generates a report card of students final grades

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const float numOfAssignments = 4;
const float assignmentWeight = 0.4;
const float midtermWeight = 0.15;
const float finalWeight = 0.35;
const float participationWeight = 0.1;

float assignmentScore();
float midtermScore();
float finalScore();
float participationScore();
string student();

int main(){

    float finalGrade, assignments, midterm, final, participation;
    string name;

    ofstream Grades;
    Grades.open("finalgrade.txt");

    name = student();
    assignments = assignmentScore();
    midterm = midtermScore();
    final = finalScore();
    participation = participationScore();


    // Adds all scores together for final grade
    finalGrade = assignments + midterm + final + participation;

    // Check if there is a file to write to
    if (Grades.is_open()){
        Grades << "***************************************************" << endl
               << "               2015 REPORT CARD                  " << endl
               << "***************************************************" << endl
               << endl;

        Grades << "Name: " << name << endl;
        Grades << "Assignment score out of 40:    " << assignments << endl;
        Grades << "Midterm score out of 15:       " << midterm << endl;
        Grades << "Final Exam score out of 35:    " << final << endl;
        Grades << "Participation score out of 10: " << participation << endl;
        Grades << "**************************************" << endl;
        Grades << "The final grade is:            " << finalGrade << endl;

        if (finalGrade > 70){
            Grades << "Congratulations you passed!" << endl;
        } else {
            Grades << "You Failed, See you again next semester." << endl;
        }

        if (finalGrade > 90){
            Grades << "****************" << endl
                   << "    *           " << endl
                   << "   * *      *   " << endl
                   << "  * * *   ***** " << endl
                   << " *     *    *   " << endl 
                   << "****************" << endl;
        }

    }
    else{
        cout << "Could not write to file because it failed to open" << endl;
    }

    Grades.close();

    return 0;
}

// Takes input and computes the average and returns a weighted score.
float assignmentScore(){

    float assign1, assign2, assign3, assign4, average;
    float assignmentScore;

    cout << "Enter the score for the first assignment: ";
    cin >> assign1;

    cout << "Enter the score for the second assignment: ";
    cin >> assign2;

    cout << "Enter the score for the third assignment: ";
    cin >> assign3;

    cout << "Enter the score for the fourth assignment: ";
    cin >> assign4;

    average = (assign1 + assign2 + assign3 + assign4) / numOfAssignments;
    assignmentScore = average * assignmentWeight;

    cout << "Assignment Score is: " << assignmentScore << endl;

    return assignmentScore;
}

float midtermScore(){

    float midterm, midtermScore;

    cout << "Enter the score for the midterm: ";
    cin >> midterm; 

    midtermScore = midterm * midtermWeight;
    cout << "Midterm Score is: " << midtermScore << endl;
    return midtermScore;
} 

float finalScore(){

    float final, finalScore;

    cout << "Enter the score for the final: ";
    cin >> final;

    finalScore = final * finalWeight;
    cout << "Final Score is: " << finalScore << endl;

    return finalScore;

}

float participationScore(){

    float participation, participationScore;

    cout << "Enter Parcipation Score: ";
    cin >> participation;

    participationScore = participation * participationWeight;
    cout << "Participation Score: " << participationScore << endl;

    return participationScore;
}

string student(){
    string first_name, last_name, student;

    cout << "Students first name: ";
    cin >> first_name;

    cout << "Students last name:";
    cin >> last_name;

    student = first_name + " " + last_name;

    return student;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations for using some constants, but you could use more in the following lines:

```
Grades << "Assignment score out of 40:    " << assignments << endl;
Grades << "Midterm score out of 15:       " << midterm << endl;
Grades << "Final Exam score out of 35:    " << final << endl;
Grades << "Participation score out of 10: " << participation << endl;
Grades << "**************************************" << endl;
Grades << "The final grade is:            " << finalGrade << endl;


if (finalGrade > 70){
```

Here the maximum score is hardcoded (written directly inside the source code), I suggest making the max scores constants too.

---

Please aviod all those prototypes:

```
float assignmentScore();
float midtermScore();
float finalScore();
float participationScore();
string student();
```

just move the main function at the end and you can delete them.

---

Please check for more errors in the UI, the following cases are not handled:

- A name with spaces is entered (such names exist so you cannot crash on them).
- Nothing happens if I enter a negative or ridiculously big number, you should put some checks for that.
- If I enter a string instead of a number the program crashes, you should handle that and ask for input again.

---

```
using namespace std;
```

[should be avoided.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

---

You could write a loop and/or a function to remove some of the duplication from below:

```
cout << "Enter the score for the first assignment: ";
cin >> assign1;

cout << "Enter the score for the second assignment: ";
cin >> assign2;

cout << "Enter the score for the third assignment: ";
cin >> assign3;

cout << "Enter the score for the fourth assignment: ";
cin >> assign4;
```

Comment: Thank You for such a detailed response this has been extremely helpful. I've been working on implementing the things you have discussed here. I am having difficulty implementing a loop with the cout and cin. This is an example of something I've tried. 'for(int i = 1; i < numOfAssignments; i++){  cout << "Enter score: ; cin >> assign[ i ] "}' but clearly that wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `using namespace std;`, or any other namespace, for that matter.  This can cause you have load functions with the same name, which can cause problems.  This is discussed in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Second, you don't need to specifically write each character in the lines of "*"s.  If you `#include <string>`, you can just write this:

```
std::cout << std::string(51, '*') << std::endl;
```

Third, follow Caridorc's advice about using more constants - or you could even consider making this more universal and allowing the professor to input the number of exams and homework assignments, the weights for each type, and other material.  Most of my professors use a different weight, what if all of them wanted to use this without making any changes?

Comment: Thank you @Hosch250 I've implemented some of the changes that you suggested and ultimately coming up with a much more robust and useful solution. I posted the updated code :)